# MySQL INSERT INTO ... VALUES and SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

Is there a way to insert pre-set values and values I get from a select-query?
For example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ("A string", 5, [int]).
```

I have the value of "A string" and the number 5, but I've to find the [int] value from a select like this:

```
SELECT idTable2
FROM table2
WHERE ...
```

that gives me that id to put inside table1.

How to merge this into one statement?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use an `insert ... select` query, and put the known values in the `select`:

```
insert into table1
select 'A string', 5, idTable2
from table2
where ...
```

Comment: A problem I've found with this approach is that if the `SELECT` returns zero records then the statement succeeds but no data is `INSERT`.

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski: Yes, but that is only a problem if you expect the result to be something else. If you want an error in that case, you can use a subquery instead.

Answer (score 100):

just use a subquery right there like:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ("A string", 5, (SELECT ...)).
```

Comment: this method may give an error like "more than 1 row"

Comment: It should be "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ("A string", 5, (SELECT ... LIMIT 1))."

Comment: This solution is very helpful when you need to copy only few values from a row in one table, into a new row in another table.

Answer (score 21):

```
INSERT INTO table_name1
            (id,
             name,
             address,
             contact_number) 
SELECT id, name, address, contact_number FROM table_name2;
```

Answer (score 12):

try this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1 , COL2,COL3) values
('A STRING' , 5 , (select idTable2 from Table2) )
where ...
```

Comment: What about multiple columns from the `SELECT` table? If I try more than one column coming from there, I get `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.

Comment: that's it . yes!

Answer (score 8):

All other answers solves the problem and my answer works the same way as the others, but just on a more didactically way (this works on MySQL... don't know other SQL servers):

```
INSERT INTO table1 SET 
  stringColumn  = 'A String', 
  numericColumn = 5, 
  selectColumn  = (SELECT idTable2 FROM table2 WHERE ...);
```

You can refer the MySQL documentation: [INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT "A string", 5, idTable2
FROM table2
WHERE ...
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table1(Table2Id, KeyTypeEnumId, SortOrder, TenantId)
    SELECT Id, 1, 1, TenantId
    FROM table2
    WHERE WebsitePageTypeEnumId = 10 AND ElementTypeEnumId = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT 'A string', 5, idTable2 idTable2 FROM table2 WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
SELECT "a string", 5, TheNameOfTheFieldInTable2
FROM table2 where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT "A string", 5, idTable2 FROM table2 WHERE ...
```