# MySQL - select in an insert

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-insert

I want to insert the IDs from one table to another along with the POST variables of a form.

```
INSERT INTO tickets (Name,Text,Betreff,priority,statusid,Date,user_id)
VALUES
    (
        '".mysql_real_escape_string( $name )."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string( $text )."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string( $betreff )."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string( $priority )."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string( $statusid )."',
        NOW() (SELECT id from login)
    )";
```

That only gets me an error!

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT id from login))' at line 10

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Did you simply miss the , ?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523597/mysql-insert-into-values-and-select?rq=1

Comment: I think you are missing where clause. how many records you are getting by running SELECT id from login

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT id from login))' at line 10

Comment: You are also missing quote after NOW().

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `WHERE` clause, selecting multiple IDs for a single `INSERT` statement.

```
SELECT id from login WHERE <?>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @iurgemaister Edited according to your comment. Thanks