# How to do a Select in an insert MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, insert

My question is how do i do a select of one attribute in my table.
I have the following table->

```
CREATE TABLE `Group` (  
  `group_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
  `user_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
  `group_creator` varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
  `group_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
   CONSTRAINT UC_Group UNIQUE (group_id,group_code,group_name)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;  
ALTER TABLE `Group`  
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),  
  ADD KEY (`user_id`);
```

I would like to insert the user_id from another table called User. However it is not working.
My insert is as follows->

```
INSERT INTO `Group` (`group_id`, `user_id`, `group_creator`, `group_name`, `date_created`)  
SET `group_id`=UUID(), `user_id`=(SELECT user_id FROM User WHERE username='TheDoctor'), `group_creator`='TheDoctor', `group_name`='HeroesUnited', `date_created`= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

Comment: Naming a table group is just asking for trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523597/mysql-insert-into-values-and-select)

```
INSERT INTO Group
SELECT UUID(),user_id,'TheDoctor','HeroesUnited', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
FROM User
WHERE username='TheDoctor'
```

Comment: It gave me an error when i added this though it worked. INSERT INTO `Group`(`group_id`, `user_id`, `group_creator`, `group_name`, `date_created`)
SO thanks!