# MySQL INSERT INTO table 1 (col1,col2,col3...) VALUE (SELECT xxx) not working

Tags: mysql

I followed this thread to build the query but mine is not working:[MySQL INSERT INTO ... VALUES and SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523597/mysql-insert-into-values-and-select) This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO item_category (id,item_name,price ) VALUES
(SELECT id, item_name, price FROM item_info WHERE item_info.price >99);
```

And this is the error message I got :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT id, item_name, price FROM item_info WHERE item_info.price >99)' at line 2
```

Comment: Remove the values and then try

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for inserting into a table from a select query does not use `VALUES`.

```
INSERT INTO item_category (id, item_name, price)
SELECT id, item_name, price
FROM item_info
WHERE price > 99;
```

The `VALUES` form of insert is reserved for inserting literal tuples, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO item_category (id, item_name, price)
VALUES
    (1, 'some item', 99);
```

Note that we could also express the above values insert using a select:

```
INSERT INTO item_category (id, item_name, price)
SELECT 1, 'some item', 99
FROM dual;    -- or some other table
```

This trick can be useful when we want to mix literals with actual column values.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Values`

```
INSERT INTO item_category (
    id
    ,item_name
    ,price
    )
SELECT id
    ,item_name
    ,price
FROM item_info
WHERE item_info.price > 99;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove VALUES and try like

```
INSERT INTO item_category (id,item_name,price )
SELECT id, item_name, price FROM item_info WHERE item_info.price >99
```

Will work!!