# Using "Select" in "Insert" statement in MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I have created a form that I link with PHP. I need the foreign key number to be the same with id of another table.

There is no problem of extracting data from the form and I test this on Error Session. Also no problem with foreign key connection on the database.

However, Select statement does not work. Is it about syntax in the insert statement ? Thanks.

```
$Connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','databasename'); 

$Query="INSERT INTO musteri_ekle(tarih,musteri_ismi,urun_id) 
VALUES('$Now','$Musteri_ismi',(SELECT urun_id from urun_ekle WHERE urun_ismi='$Urun_ismi'))";

$Execute=mysqli_query($Connection,$Query);

        if($Execute){

            $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]= "Müşteri Eklendi.";
            redirect_to("musteri_ekle.php");


} else {

     $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= $Urun_ismi." -- ".$Musteri_ismi;
     redirect_to("musteri_ekle.php");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `select` inside `values`.

Change your code from

```
$Query="INSERT INTO musteri_ekle(tarih,musteri_ismi,urun_id) 
VALUES('$Now','$Musteri_ismi',(SELECT urun_id from urun_ekle WHERE urun_ismi='$Urun_ismi'))";
```

to below:

```
$Query="INSERT INTO musteri_ekle(tarih,musteri_ismi,urun_id) 
SELECT '$Now','$Musteri_ismi',urun_id from urun_ekle WHERE urun_ismi='$Urun_ismi'";
```

Comment: Works perfect ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Alternate syntax

$Query="INSERT INTO musteri_ekle SET tarih = '$Now' ,musteri_ismi = '$Musteri_ismi' ,urun_id = (SELECT urun_id from urun_ekle WHERE urun_ismi='$Urun_ismi')";

This type of problem is discussed here [MySQL INSERT INTO ... VALUES and SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523597/mysql-insert-into-values-and-select)