# Query multiple tables based on id of first table

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, subquery

I need to fill a datatables with data from two different tables.
Easy, i would think, just join or subquery.
Unfortunately the second table is not based on ID, so i cannot filter on that one. Even if i could, i don't know how to put it in the datatables.

I've searched for days now, still no luck on this..

Table wp_mollie_forms_registrations has:

```
#id  # description #
#----#-------------#
#100 # Race #
#101 # Pull #
####################
```

Table wp_mollie_forms_registration_fields has:

```
#id  # field # value
#----#------#-------#
#100 # Naam # Theun #
#100 # E-mail # test@test.com #
#100 # Leeftijd # 28 #
#100 # Soort voertuig # Auto #
#100 # Betaalmethode # ideal #
#101 # Naam # Theun    #
#101 # E-mail# quest@write.nl #
#101 # Woonplaats # Groningen #
#101 # Merk en type # New Holland #
#101 # Gewichtsklasse # 2.8T #
#101 # Betaalmethode # ideal #
#####################
```

This is the code:

```
$query = "select * from A";
$items_result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die;

if ($items_result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table id='table_id' class='display'><thead><tr><th>ID</th> 
<th>description</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead> 
</tbody>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items_result)){
echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["description"]."</td> 
<td>".$Name."</td><td>".$row["Age"]."</td><td>".$row["Email"]."</td>
</tr>";
}
```

How would i do the following?:
select * from table_A and use id to select name, age and email, put this info in my datatables and go to next line?

EDIT: It works, but not showing Naam (name) E-mail and Age (leeftijd) I now have:

```
$query = "SELECT wp_mollie_forms_registrations.id, wp_mollie_forms_registrations.description, tn.value AS 'Naam', te.value AS 'E-mail', ta.value AS 'Leeftijd' ".
"FROM wp_mollie_forms_registrations".
" INNER JOIN (SELECT registration_id, value FROM wp_mollie_forms_registration_fields WHERE field = 'Naam') tn ON wp_mollie_forms_registrations.id = tn.registration_id".
" INNER JOIN (SELECT registration_id, value FROM wp_mollie_forms_registration_fields WHERE field = 'E-mail') te ON wp_mollie_forms_registrations.id = te.registration_id".
" INNER JOIN (SELECT registration_id, value FROM wp_mollie_forms_registration_fields WHERE field = 'Leeftijd') ta ON wp_mollie_forms_registrations.id = ta.registration_id";
if(!mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn); }
$items_result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die;

if ($items_result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table id='table_id' class='display'><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>description</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead></tbody>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items_result)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["description"]."</td><td>".$row["tn.value"]."</td><td>".$row["ta.value"]."</td><td>".$row["te.value"]."</td>
</tr>";
}
    echo "</tbody></table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: you might use a select inside your insert. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523597/mysql-insert-into-values-and-select ...

Comment: "put this info in my datatables" - What do you mean? Do you want to copy the data into another table?

Comment: I tried to identify my html table as datatables, as i thought people would know what it was..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that should work based on your responses:

```
$query = "SELECT wp_mollie_forms_registrations.id as 'ID', wp_mollie_forms_registrations.description as 'Description', tn.value AS 'Naam', te.value AS 'Email', ta.value AS 'Leeftijd' ".
"FROM wp_mollie_forms_registrations".
" INNER JOIN (SELECT registration_id, value FROM wp_mollie_forms_registration_fields WHERE field = 'Naam') tn ON wp_mollie_forms_registrations.id = tn.registration_id".
" INNER JOIN (SELECT registration_id, value FROM wp_mollie_forms_registration_fields WHERE field = 'E-mail') te ON wp_mollie_forms_registrations.id = te.registration_id".
" INNER JOIN (SELECT registration_id, value FROM wp_mollie_forms_registration_fields WHERE field = 'Leeftijd') ta ON wp_mollie_forms_registrations.id = ta.registration_id";
if(!mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn); }
$items_result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die;

if ($items_result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table id='table_id' class='display'><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>description</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead></tbody>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items_result)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["ID"]."</td><td>".$row["Description"]."</td><td>".$row["Naam"]."</td><td>".$row["Leeftijd"]."</td><td>".$row["Email"]."</td>
</tr>";
}
    echo "</tbody></table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

The reason you were not getting certain columns to show is because you had the wrong values in the 'echo' statement in PHP. For example, `tn.value as Naam` defines `tn.value` as 'Naam'. So changing the values in the PHP to reflect that should let the query work.

For a more detailed description of what the query is doing, here is an ultra simplified version. Imagine you have to tables, A and B, and each has a field 'id' and 'value'. Take a look at this query:

```
SELECT A.value, B.value
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id
```

This will select the values from tables A and B and return them, but ONLY IF there exists a match between the ids in A and the ids in B. You can read more about joins [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

The subquery part is relatively simple. It selects all 'registration_id's and 'value's from table B where the field is a specific type, such as 'Naam'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this gives me a 500 error.
See my question for what i now have.

Comment: @TheundeVries,  I just saw I was missing a quotation mark before the semicolon. Putting that in may fix the issue. I added the PHP-friendly code below.

Comment: Wow, how did i not see that myself.. i already tried the 'php friendly version' myself, but was also missing the quotation Mark.. i'll look into it een i'm sobered up.

Comment: Quickly tried it, got a white page with no errors, will look into it further when i have time.

Comment: Not working at all.. Even when i try this:
$query = "SELECT id, description".
"FROM wp_mollie_forms_registrations";
$items_result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Query wrong');

I get 'Query wrong'
I think the ". " at the end of each line is not working, not sure why

Comment: Run this and copy and paste the error message: `$query = "SELECT A.des .... ta.id"; if(!mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn); }`. Just paste in the rest of the query in the variable.

Comment: First one was: Error: Table 'wp_mollie_forms_registrationsINNER' doesn't exist
After some spaces:  Error: Unknown column 'A.id' in 'field list'
If i remove all the A. it goes on: Error: Unknown column 'tn.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: You need to change the variables A and B to replace your table names.

Comment: See my edit in the first question. It now works, but only shows ID and Description.. i tried some stuff but cannot get a grip on it. Could you explain what this does?: ta ON wp_mollie_forms_registrations.id = ta.registration_id

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual table names and column names as well as the category names in table 2. Just leave them in the language they are in. I will update the answer once you provide this information

Comment: As requested. I did filter out some other stuff in the table i do not want to use like 'created_at'.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I'll now try to put the other fields in it too myself.